# How to properly swap values of a field between two recordsets that were also queried by those values in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am encountering a strange bug when I try to swap values between two recordsets. The source of the problem appears to come from the fact that the field I am swapping is also the field that I query from initially.
Here are the logical steps to understand it more clearly:

1. Store all the records where PhaseID is equal to X into Recordset A
2. Store all the records where PhaseID is equal to Y into Recordset B
3. Set all records in Recordset A to have PhaseID equal to Y
4. Set all records in Recordset B to have PhaseID equal to X

Here is my actual code:

```
Private Sub swapReferences(firstRec() As Variant, secondRec() As Variant)
      ...
      Set rstFirst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Scenarios Where PhaseID = " & firstRec(0))
      Set rstSecond = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Scenarios Where PhaseID = " & secondRec(0))

      updateRecords rstFirst, "PhaseID", secondRec(0)
      updateRecords rstSecond, "PhaseID", firstRec(0)
End Sub

Private Sub updateRecords(rst As Recordset, fieldName As String, newVal As Variant)
     While Not rst.EOF
        rst.Edit
        rst(fieldName) = newVal
        rst.update
        rst.MoveNext
     Wend
End Sub
```

The strange thing is that this code may work the first time (in that the values are actually swapped). But the second time, it is almost guaranteed to fail. What happens is that instead of the rows being swapped, one of the recordsets gets all of the records and the other gets none. It is as if rstSecond gets dynamically larger when rstFirst updates its records to have the values that rstSecond had queried with.

What is even stranger is that I seemed to have found a fix that does not make any sense. I modified the first function as shown:

```
Private Sub swapReferences(firstRec() As Variant, secondRec() As Variant)
    Set rstFirst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Scenarios Where PhaseID = " & firstRec(0))
    Set rstSecond = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Scenarios Where PhaseID = " & secondRec(0))

    'Debug
    If Not rstSecond.EOF Then
       'For whatever reason .RecordCount isn't accurate unless the last record has been accessed
       rstSecond.MoveLast
       Debug.Print rstSecond.RecordCount
       rstSecond.MoveFirst
    End If

    updateRecords rstFirst, "PhaseID", secondRec(0)

    'Debug
    If Not rstSecond.EOF Then
       rstSecond.MoveLast
       Debug.Print rstSecond.RecordCount
       rstSecond.MoveFirst
    End If

    updateRecords rstSecond, "PhaseID", firstRec(0)
End Sub
```

Those if blocks were used to see if rstSecond was magically changing its size after rstFirst updated its records. When I ran the code with these debug blocks, I discovered that not only was rstSecond remaining constant but my code worked as intended.

So my question is two-fold: why did adding those debug blocks fix my code? And is there a more appropriate way to do what I want to do so my code does not appear to be so nonsensical?

Comment: It's possible the second recordset's records aren't actually retrieved until after the first recordset's updates are sent to the database.  The MoveLast forces the retreival to happen *before* the updates to the other recordset are sent.  Another approach would be to wait until all updates are done and then call UpdateBatch on both recordsets.

Comment: Do you mean to wait until both recordset's records are retrieved? How does one force it to wait?

Comment: Instead of calling `update` within each loop, wait until both recordset have been updated and then call `updatebatch` on each one.

Comment: Okay I understand now. However, I am using DAO recordsets. Still, I tried running `rstFirst.update dbUpdateBatch` but it throws me an invalid argument exception. Would this be a good reason to switch to an ADO recordset?

Comment: I never use DAO, but maybe try checking here first:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-updateoptions-property-dao

Comment: It is unclear to me whether or not any of these [UpdateCriteriaEnum values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/updatecriteriaenum-enumeration-dao) will give me what I want.

Comment: You'll have to try them out...

Comment: Have you tried unbinding the recordset variable and then bind it again? that way should get you the updated recordset. Also, don't know how many records you got, but maybe `DoEvents` could help.